# Can I import a list of contact name as the definition of a group

Tags: macbook-pro, email, contacts, group

I need to create a Group in Contacts on my mac book air. Each contact in the group already has a contact card. I know I can drag contacts into a new group but that is too labor intensive, error prone, and doesn't alway work (I replaced my group with a contact by accident for example).
Is there a batch way to create a contact group, say from a file with a list of contact keys (e.f first and last name)?